# Maven - Excluding Resource from a specific artifact

Tags: maven, resourcebundle

I'm new to maven, and found myself stuck with something which is really bothering me.

I have a multi-module project, and my parent pom.xml contains the following plugin:

```
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-remote-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resourceBundles>
                            <resourceBundle>
                                ${shared.resources.version}
                            </resourceBundle>
                        </resourceBundles>
                        <includes>
                            <include>version.info</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This code generates a version.info file and places them in each of my module jar files.
I was wondering if it's possible to make this code create the version.info file for only 2 modules out of the 3.

For example if I have modules: A, B and C.
I would like the version.info file to be in A and B but not in C.
I hope I explained myself well enough, in case not please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Meny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution would be moving this plugin configuration to the project/build/pluginManagement element of the parent pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-remote-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resourceBundles>
                           <resourceBundle>
                            ${shared.resources.version}
                           </resourceBundle>
                        </resourceBundles>
                        <includes>
                           <include>version.info</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

and call it at project/build/plugins in module poms:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

if such refactoring of parent pom is not allowed then override plugin configuration with skip set into true or use the none phase to disable unwanted plugin calls:
http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/howto-disable-inherited-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I did what you suggested and moved it from the parent POM to the relevant module's pom and it did the trick